# How to save "state" of of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

using Objective-C

I have a table with cell that can be swiped (as example use [this post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views) with some changes in logic). Currently i can swipe cell and after flipping table it's "state" will be reset to "closed". I want to implement some "memory" mechanism for storing last state of each cell.

How I try to do it - in cell class create protocol, where implement 2 methods for getting current indexPath of cell and adding it to the NSMutableSet, and before presenting it, controller check if this cell already in collection - set required state.

I use separate .xib files for both viewController with tableView and tableViewCell.

Code - `cell.h` class file:

```
@protocol PEDoctorsViewTableViewCellDelegate
@optional
//buttonAction
- (void)buttonDeleteAction;
//method for closing cell with swipe
- (void)cellDidSwipedIn: (UITableViewCell*)cell;
//method for opening cell with swipe
- (void)cellDidSwipedOut:(UITableViewCell *)cell;
@end 
@interface PEDoctorsViewTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <PEDoctorsViewTableViewCellDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <PEDoctorsViewTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
//method for protocol PEDoctorsViewTableViewCellDelegate
- (void)setCellSwiped;
@end
```

`cell.m` file

```
...
//add some code for handling reuse of cells
//fixing issue with not remembeering of cell's state
//close all cells during flipping tableView
- (void)prepareForReuse{
[super prepareForReuse];
//close all cells before showing
self.viewDoctorsNameView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.viewDoctorsNameView.frame.size.width, self.viewDoctorsNameView.frame.size.height);
}
```

And `viewController with tableView class.m`

```
#pragma mark - PEDoctorsViewTableViewCellDelegate

- (void)cellDidSwipedOut:(UITableViewCell *)cell{
    NSIndexPath * currentOpenedCellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.currentlySwipedAndOpenesCells addObject:currentOpenedCellIndexPath];
}

- (void)cellDidSwipedIn:(UITableViewCell *)cell{
    [self.currentlySwipedAndOpenesCells removeObject:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]];
}

- (void)buttonDeleteAction {
    NSLog(@"delete action");
}
```

and check in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method like

```
if ([self.currentlySwipedAndOpenesCells containsObject:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]]){
    [cell setCellSwiped];
}
```

also this class have

```
//place to store set of opened cells
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet * currentlySwipedAndOpenesCells;
```

initialized in `- (void)viewDidLoad`.

As result - i got all cells with reset position.

- I try to change code in `- (void)prepareForReuse` method - position of cell changes according to my changes in method - this part works fine.
- Try to check delegate method - all fire in exactly required moment.
- Try to add some `NSLog` method before adding object in `NSMuatbaleSet` and before cell will be recreated (think maybe data lost) - result - during adding object in to set - all looks like OK:

[image]

During recreating - looks like OK too :

[image]

but not changes in table shown. I try to check what object are captured during saving -

[image]

and after small flip for starting recreating process got next:

[image]

as I understand - same cell now a new object. Also try to add some BOOL property to cell for controlling and comparing it's state - result the same - each time new cell.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: With any TableView you must maintain the "state" of the out-of-view cells.  You design that first, before the TableView itself.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` simply maps from your state to the actual UI objects.  How are you keeping the main data for each cell?  (I'm not going to spend the time to weed through the above core dump to figure it out.)

Comment: for every cell i store it's indexPath in NSMutableSet after swiping using `NSIndexPath * currentOpenedCellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.currentlySwipedAndOpenesCells addObject:currentOpenedCellIndexPath];`

Comment: So you don't have, eg, an NSArray that's a 1:1 map between your conceptual values and the TableView cells?  How do you know how to populate a cell in the first place??

Comment: now i dont add any data in to cell, only some text using `cell.doctorNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Doctor number %d", [indexPath row]];`

Comment: So your table is merely "Doctor number 1", "Doctor number 2", "Doctor number 3"... with no other data??  And you intend it to stay that way -- never add names or state info, other than your "swiped" state?

Comment: currently yes, later i'll add some values instead of "Doctor number 1", "Doctor number 2", "Doctor number 3"... And now what i need (and later also) - is to save state (swiped or no) - because after flipping table up/down i want to recover spipped state

Comment: That's why you have a data structure "along side" the table.  Generally an NSMutableArray, containing either custom objects or NSMutableDictionarys -- one per potential table row.  Your "real" data goes there, and it gets copied to the cell by cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: u mean due to lack of my datastructure i have such problem?

Comment: Correct. You should really look to follow the MVC model. I'd suggest creating a doctor class, keep an array of doctor objects, and then having a property in the doctor class for whether or not it's swiped/edited.

Comment: No need to create a doctor class.  A simple NSMutableDictionary works just as well and is easier to maintain.